# Is there a way to swap cross-sells and up-sells easily?

Tags: up-sells, cross-sells

I'm the guy that does the data entry for our cross-sells and up-sells on our store page.  Unfortunately, the marketing person would like all cross-sells and up-sells to be swapped.  Is this possible?  Failing that, is there a better way to gather product ID's for copy and paste purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Up-sells and cross-sells relations are both kept in the same table: `catalog_product_link`.
the only difference between the 2 relations it the `link_type_id` column.
For up-sells the value is 4 and for cross-sells it is 5.

so you can swap them through a single query:

```
UPDATE 
    `catalog_product_link` 
SET 
    `link_type_id` = 9 - `link_type_id` 
WHERE 
    `link_type_id` IN (4,5)
```

But back up the table first.

Comment: That's a very clever 'hack' using 9 - x to switch the numbers.

Comment: @Cags. I was good at math and "twisted" problems when I was young. I still remember some tricks :)

Comment: Hopefully you never forget you did the twist ...

Comment: You're a saint!