# Further questions about swapping cross-sells and up-sells

Tags: up-sells, cross-sells

Last week I asked a question about swapping the two.  I was given a solution ( [Is there a way to swap cross-sells and up-sells easily?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58420/is-there-a-way-to-swap-cross-sells-and-up-sells-easily) ).
Today my guy tried to implement it and got this error:
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '5-6194-9438' for key 'UNQ_mg_CAT_PRD_LNK_LNK_TYPE_ID_PRD_ID_LNKED_PRD_ID'

Is there something we're missing?

Answer (score 1):

Barry,remove `foreign key` from table  using `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`then run marius  update query. after that enable foreign  key of table   `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;`

Make a clone  of table catalog_product_link.I guess table is close table name is **catalog_product_link_cp**

**Query 1:**

```
UPDATE catalog_product_link  
SET catalog_product_link.link_type_id = 4 where  catalog_product_link.link_id in (select catalog_product_link_cp.link_id from catalog_product_link_cp where catalog_product_link_cp.link_type_id = 5  )
```

**Query 2:**

```
UPDATE catalog_product_link  
SET catalog_product_link.link_type_id = 5 where  catalog_product_link.link_id in (select catalog_product_link_cp.link_id from catalog_product_link_cp where catalog_product_link_cp.link_type_id = 4  )
```